# Unable to save object due to constraint even with supplied properties

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have an object `Number`, with fields non-nullable. In integration tests, when I tried to save the object it fails due to `ConstraintViolationException` which is likely weird since I supplied all the needed fields.

Details of my test

```
//other initializations needed for test  here

NumberGroup numberGroup = new NumberGroup();
    NumberGroupService.getDao().save(numberGroup);
    String numberGroupId = Long.toString(numberGroup.getId());

Number number = new Number("0987", true,numberGroup);
numberService.getDao().save(number);

//the rest of integration tests
```

I got the details below for the stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [insert into number (field2, number_group_id, field1) values (?, ?, ?)]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
...
...
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into number (field2, number_group_id, field1) values ('1', 28, '0987') was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
```

And below is the details of `Number` object. The `@GenerateDao` annotation is just to simplify every object to generate own dao with just the annotation.

```
@Data
@Entity
@GenerateDao
public class Number {

    @Id
    private String field1;

    private boolean field2;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "number_group_id", columnDefinition = "BIGINT")
    private NumberGroup numberGroup;

    public Number() {

    }

    public Number(String field1, boolean field2, NumberGroup numberGroup) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
        this.numberGroup = numberGroup;
    }
}
```

On stacktrace, it also shows it has values needed. In case more details are needed, let me know.

Comment: Does your `save(...)` actually commit the object ?

Comment: It does, for all objects except the `Number` object.